# How to get the dynamic path of solution directory in post-build event of Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, post-build-event

I have seven code library project in my solution and I has 3 different type of websites which are using same code library project from VSS.

Now I want to put post build script in one of my reference code library project so that when build it done it put one specific DLL to my website bin directory.

So example, I have reference project with name "references" and in its project property will put below code to get the solution website bin directory.

```
xcopy /Y $(ProjectDir)Tridion $(SolutionDir)Com.Emirates.Pss.Ibe.UI\Bin
```

Above things works fine for my one website project who name is "Com.Emirates.Pss.Ibe.UI", the problem comes as one user checked in the "references" project and then other developer takes the latest of references project it gets "Com.Emirates.Pss.Ibe.UI" in its post build script, however its solution website directory is "Com.Emirates.Pss.MYBooking.UI".

How can I make xcopy /Y $(ProjectDir)Tridion $(SolutionDir)**Com.Emirates.Pss.Ibe.UI**\Bin (bold part dynamic, so that who ever does the checked in user can easily build there application without doing the changes.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list of all the different [Post-Build event macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/pre-build-event-post-build-event-command-line-dialog-box#macros).

I'm guessing you want to use the **$(ProjectDir)** macro, if I understood correctly?

**Another option** if you are using MSBuild you can add [User Defined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2t8ztwy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) variables in VS, create your own [property sheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak4435es%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as shown in the example:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
      <MyProj>Com.Emirates.Pss.Ibe.UI</MyProj>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Usage: `xcopy /Y $(ProjectDir)Tridion $(SolutionDir)$(MyProj)\Bin`

**And one last option**, is setting an environment variable with the name of the specific project in MAIN project (which will run before) and reference it from the `references` project.

e.g.

In project #1 set a **Pre**-Build event with:
`SETX MyProj Com.Emirates.Pss.Ibe.UI`

In Reference project, copy it using 
`xcopy /Y $(ProjectDir)Tridion $(SolutionDir)%MyProj%\Bin`

It should be noted the difference between SETX and SET is that SETX keeps the variables even after the CMD window (which runs MSBuild) closes. BUT, you might have to close and reopen Visual Studio the first time you run this as a variable created with SETX only starts working on any CMD window that is created AFTER using this command.

Comment: $(ProjectDir) will give current project directory, however I want to copy the dlls of my website bin directory which is configured with solution

Comment: Updated my answer with another option

Comment: where do I need to create </PropertyGroup>
is that I need to create in code project or it is in website...If it needs to be created in code project which is shared by other solution then above solution will not work for me as in that case 1 user does the changes according to his project and does the check in and then 2 user takes latest from vss then he gets same setting for his project...please suggest

Comment: @M.S Is setting an environment variable a feasible option?

Answer (score 0):

I simply pass $(SolutionDir) as an argument to the .cmd file you are invoking in your PostBuild event command line. Similarily if you want $(ProjectName) or any other of the VS macros accessible in the PostBuild cmd.

Comment: I need to take one DLLs from other project then copy to solution website bin directory on its post build event

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by putting below code in "references" project PostBuildEvent:

```
if $(SolutionName) == IbeUI-Integrated  xcopy /Y $(ProjectDir)Tridion $(SolutionDir)Com.Emirates.Pss.Ibe.UI\Bin
if $(SolutionName) == MybUI-Integrated  xcopy /Y $(ProjectDir)Tridion $(SolutionDir)Com.Emirates.Pss.Myb.UI\Bin
if $(SolutionName) == OlciUI-Integrated  xcopy /Y $(ProjectDir)Tridion $(SolutionDir)Com.Emirates.Pss.Olci.UI\Bin
```